# jquery hash trigger click

Tags: jquery, hash, triggers, click

i have search but nothing came up to solve the problem i'm having, at least none that i read and i read a lot. :) my problem is that when someone goes to a url with a hash (ex: mysite.com/gallery/#image-name-1) i can make the class for it "current" so it shows as the clicked image but i can't trigger the click function so that it will show the full size gallery image and information. my page is setup like with a big gallery image (pulls onclick and needs to pull by just the hash) and under it is a grid of thumbnails to click.

all help is appreciated. thanks in advance!!!

```
function gallery_grid()
{
    var gallery_url = document.location.toString();

    if(gallery_url.match('#'))
    {
        var gallery_anchor = '#' + gallery_url.split('#')[1];

        $('ul.gallery-grid li a[href="' + gallery_anchor + '"]').addClass('current');
        $('ul.gallery-grid li a[href="' + gallery_anchor + '"]').trigger('click'); /* need this to trigger the click function so i can pull info from it for the bigger gallery image */
    }
    else
    {
        $('ul.gallery-grid li:first a').addClass('current');
    }

    $('ul.gallery-grid li a').click(function()
    {
        // stuff goes here to grab from $(this) but it can't cause it's not triggered
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to add the click function first.

Comment: If you put a console.log inside the `if(gallery_url.match('#'))`, does it return a result to your javascript console?

Comment: got it working. tanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to trigger the `click` before you've added the `click` handler to the element. Move the `if` statement underneath the `click` handler.

Comment: i switched it around and it works now but not the image part. it can't get the img src? any idea? tanks!

Comment: got it working! forgot that i split the class and needed to do clicked_class[0] tanks for the help everyone! hours of frustration for two simple things... haha. :)